# Error in nmatrix installation: suffix or operands invalid for `movq'

Tags: c++, ruby, gcc, nmatrix

I tried installing using `gem install nmatrix` on osx, using gcc 5.2.0.

```
In file included from nmatrix.cpp:283:0:
[some warnings ...]
/var/folders/sc/2zd_v0qn76gdq5sdg63_jx4r0000gn/T//cc1KmZTQ.s:13579:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
make: *** [nmatrix.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

I tried to look at `cc1KmZTQ.s`, but this file doesn't exist after the error.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you attempt with GCC 4.9?

Comment: Yep, with slightly different warnings
https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix/issues/406#issuecomment-155498537